# top command in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I want to see all the java processes & see the details of it in linux.

I'm using top command & it shows me all processes along with java.

But I would like to know if there is any way top command will show only java processes. 
I've many java programs running in my server & I want the top command to list only java processes so that I can see the details of them.

Is this possible? How can I do it in top command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install **[`htop`](http://htop.sourceforge.net/)**, press <kbd>\</kbd>, then enter `java` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of top, use ps and if you want it to be refreshed periodically, use watch.
For example:

```
watch -n 1 'ps aux | grep java'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
top -p `pgrep -d, -f java`
```

Explanation:

```
 top -p pid[,pid,pid]
```

Provides top a list of pids to watch.

```
`pgrep -d, -f java`
```

Does a grep of the process names for 'java', and returns the comma seperated pid values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have JDK ( unlikely on production servers)  installed, there are set of tools that works with java process.  [jps/jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html) etc

Comment: `jps` (as well as `jstat`,`jstatd`, and `jconsole`) is marked as _experimental_ and _unsupported_ in the Java 1.5 [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/index.html#manage). Same thing for `jmap` and its ilk (`jinfo`, `jsadebugd`, and `jstack`) - in the 1.5 [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/index.html#debug). The Java 7 documentation has identical warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter output, so you can use 'grep' command,
direct 'top' output using a pipeline '|'. So your command should look something like:
top | grep java

If you just need to know info in one point of time you can use:
ps aux | grep java